# Get long term access token for Facebook page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm using [Jquery Facebook Wall](https://github.com/thomasclausen/jquery-facebook-wall) to retrieve the latest status of a Facebook page and show it in a website.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#facebook_wall').facebook_wall({
            id: '560124337XXXXX',
            access_token: 'CXGXhXZA7Wg2XXDcTi7WmX1wp71u5fNXXa9XXX3LmXXx',
            limit: 1
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

// ...
```

When I use [FB Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get the `access token` of the page, I get one that expire in only 60 minutes. Is there a way to get a long duration `access token`? Or to generate a new one each time a user connect to the website page?

PHP is not allowed since the website isn't hosted in an Apache server. I'm seeking a client-side solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update :** According to my researches, I assume that getting a token that doesn't expire in one month and that have `Manage Pages` permission (the only permission that grant reading a page feeds), require the creation of a Facebook app that include "Facebook login" and then waiting for the "Review Process" approval.

I don't have any intention to make people login since it's a static website. Is there a *possibility* to get a static access token that doesn't expire in an hour and that have the permission of "reading page's feed", without creating the app, adding a privacy policy page URL for it, waiting for the review process, making people login... And without resorting to server-side options?

Comment: Extending tokens requires your app secret, and that doesn’t belong into client-side code. And if your app is purely client-side, then what would you need extended tokens for anyway? You can just get a fresh short-lived on every time the user uses your app … (and the JS SDK will see to it that you always have a valid one on its own.)

Comment: And any other token that is not the viewing user’s own does not belong into the code either. If you want to do this purely client-side, then you have to make people login to your app first, so that you can use their token.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CBroe. How can I get a fresh short-lived on every time the user connect to the website page? The website is static and I don't have any intention to make people login!

Comment: In that case there is no responsible way of implementing this purely client-side. The page plugin is your only other option then.

Comment: Can you explain more about the "page plugin" please?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Answer (score 0):

How to generate different Tokens (App Token, User Token, Page Token, Extended User Token, Extended Page Token) is explained very well in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Here´s another link if that is not enough:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

As CBroe commented, you don´t need extended Tokens client-side. For getting the feed of a Page, an App Token is good enough - but you should NEVER expose your App Secret on the client. It is called Secret for a reason. And i hope you´re not trying to use static Token like that for every user. Whatever Token you are using, don´t expose it to any other users.

You could also just use the Page Plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin (again, thanx to CBroe for pointing out that additional solution).

Comment: I want to use a static access token for every user, is there a possibility to achieve that? I don't think it will be a security issue since the token will have only reading permissions to read information that are available publicly.

Comment: you need to use a server language for that, so you can use a static token. it does not have to be PHP, of course. that way, you can just use an app token, it is valid forever.

Comment: What about using that static token in client-side? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: possible or not, it is a VERY bad idea

Comment: I need a token that have only reading permissions, it will have access only to publicly available information! Is there a documentation or a tutorial for how to get this access token so I can get it working with the client-side script that I'm using?

Comment: there are 2 links for that in my answer, explaining how to get all the different tokens. extended user tokens are valid for 60 days. but again, tokens are not something you should expose to anyone else, with whatever permissions.