# Facebook graph API - how to use in front-end without user login and obtaining access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've embedded facebook comments plugin on the bottom of my page and it shows 0 comments. Than I wanted to show that count on the top of my page, so I used FQL to get comment count of a link, but it returned different value (41). As FQL is deprecated I tried graph API. It returns valid values, but how do I use it in front-end app without user login and obtaining access token? Can I use it on behalf of app?

note: I don't want to use `<span class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://example.com/"></span>` as I'm using odometer to animate numbers

Comment: You want to get only comments count?

Comment: We discussed a similar issue here recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025307/get-long-term-access-token-for-facebook-page If you want to do it client-side, then your only viable option is to make users login to your app first, so that you can use their user access token.

Answer (score -1):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{post-id}/comments?summary=true&format=json&access_token=app-id|app-secret
```

But remember in mind that app access_token should'nt be shared on client side. i gave solution just because you asked for it,

Comment: you can´t use that on the client. the app secret is called secret for a reason.

Comment: see what he wants, he doesnt want users to login into his website. and to read from facebook you need access_token. May be he is making fb application just to communicate with fb sdk only. so his app secret valued at nothing.

Comment: That’s nonsense – the app access token allows changing a lot of app settings etc. It does simply not belong in client-side code that is publicly available, not ever.

Comment: i am not saying app access token is of no importance. what i am saying is just an answer to what he asked. with out user login this is the only solution.

Comment: sorry, but that´s not an answer, that´s just something you should NEVER do and you should not even suggest it. people can (and will) get ideas.