# Facebook Graph API: Client side requests without user login?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get graph api data for public Facebook events rendered in an html document. The site I need to put it on is made with a website builder so I don't have control over the server that generates the html. I can only insert JavaScript code into the page.

The only solution I've found now is by using an app access_token in the client side request:

```
  FB.api(
    "/<event_id>?fields=start_time,description",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response.start_time, response.description);
      }
    },
    {access_token: "<app access token>"}
  );
```

I've read through [the docs on access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)
and [the JavaScript sdk docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript), but the app token solution I've found is not secure (from the docs):

> ... app access token should never be hard-coded into client-side code.

I don't think the user access token is the flow I want because I don't want people to have to log in; it's only for public events. I don't think the page access token is right either.

Is there:

1. a way to use the Graph API for public events without requiring a user to log in or without introducing an insecurity?
2. or a way to make sharing my app access token with the world have no bad consequences?

Comment: No, and no. If you don’t want users to login to your app, then you have to request the data server-side. See also this recent discussion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025307/get-long-term-access-token-for-facebook-page

Comment: @CBroe it sounds like I may need to basically proxy the request through a server I control to hide the app secret... ugh now I need another server...